# enviar formulario sem dar refresh na página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom estou montando o código em jquery que vai fazer o envio do formulário, ele esta funcionando. Porém estou com umas dúvidas e não sei como resolver.

1º - Para evitar que eu tenho que fazer um javascript muito repetitivo eu queria saber como fazer para colocar o link na tag 'action' do 'form' e fazer o jquery capturar o Link e colocar ele no 'url: "fone2.php",'.

Isso iria fazer com que eu usasse o mesmo código para todos os form.

2º - Preciso capturar a mensagem do arquivo que recebe o form e colocar no ' alert("sdfsdf");'.

Alguém pode me ajudar com essas alterações.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function() {
      var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fone2.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function() {
          alert("sdfsdf");
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
< script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

  <form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form">
    <input type="text" name="nome" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que isso vá funcionar do jeito que precisa.

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function() {
    var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
    //aqui voce pega o conteudo do atributo action do form
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: dados,
      success: function(response) {
        //'response' é a resposta do servidor
        alert(response);
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="minha-url.php" id="ajax_form">
  <input type="text" name="nome" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: vlw era isso mesmo, muito obrigado